# How does Fibonacci heap delay work as long as possible?

Tags: algorithm, clrs, fibonacci-heap

I am reading [**CLRS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) and came across a line "Fibonacci heaps delay works as long as possible".But what does it actually mean by delaying works and how can that be related to performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he explained very clearly in the book. You should notice that when an element is **added** to the heap, there is **no work done** O(1) , the new element is just simply attached to the root, and the heap is only reorganized until an element is removed.( Look at the exactMin function). And that's why he means all the work is *delayed as long as possible*